# Failure events behavoir for DISCONNECT Intent

Tags: actions-on-google, disconnect, google-smart-home, google-assistant

I'm implementing a Handler for the DISCONNECT Intent, and by reading the online documentation  https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/intent/disconnect, I see that it is no such response format and it is not a reference in case of fail event, when for example we return an error in event that we didn't properly handle the disconnect or Google API did not reach our server. Does Google Assistant implement some sort of automatic retry logic so that in event of error it automatically resends the requests for a certain amount time. In other words is it a way to tell to the google assistant to retry or return some error to the user that made the DISCONNECT request?

Comment: Have you tried returning a simple error status code like `500`?

Comment: Hi Nick, indeed I did a try returning the global-error event "hardError" with this shape: {"requestId": "ff36a3cc-ec34-11e6-b1a0-64510650abcf","payload": {"errorCode": "hardError","status" : "ERROR"}}, but I had no results: when I did unlink action on google assistant it is successful.

Comment: I also did a try throwing an Error (which reduces to a 500 status) with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

There is no response format for the DISCONNECT intent in the https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/intent/disconnect documentation because nothing is returned when the action.devices.DISCONNECT intent is executed (eg. Google does not retry based on your response status code). You can find more information on this at https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/process-intents#unlink
After an action.devices.DISCONNECT intent is sent, the Assistant stops sending any more intents for the user who has just been disconnected, and the associated cloud service also stops calling Home Graph APIs (Request Sync and Report State) for their devices and a SYNC request is triggered.